# How do you make an encrypted swap partition setup persistent across boots?

Tags: lvm, swap, dmcrypt

I have a procedure which will manually create a plain dm-crypt swap volume, with a random key, which appears to work. This is a QEMU/Ubuntu 22.04 system. However, there's no swap after a reboot, so I've presumably got my `/etc/crypttab` and/or `/etc/fstab`, or something else, incorrect. Any input appreciated.

The working manual setup is:

```
    # swapoff -a
    # cryptsetup --type plain open /dev/mapper/vg0-swap encswap
    # mkswap /dev/mapper/encswap
    # /etc/init.d/cryptdisks start
    # swapon /dev/mapper/encswap
    
    # swapon -s
    Filename                Type        Size        Used    Priority
    /dev/dm-3               partition   2097148     0       -2
    # lsblk
    NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
    sda             8:0    0   50G  0 disk  
    ├─sda1          8:1    0    1M  0 part  
    ├─sda2          8:2    0    1G  0 part  /boot
    ├─sda3          8:3    0   13G  0 part  
    │ ├─vg0-swap  253:0    0    2G  0 lvm   
    │ │ └─encswap 253:3    0    2G  0 crypt [SWAP]
    │ ├─vg0-data  253:1    0 36.1G  0 lvm   /data
    │ └─vg0-root  253:2    0 10.9G  0 lvm   /
    └─sda4          8:4    0   36G  0 part  
      └─vg0-data  253:1    0 36.1G  0 lvm   /data
    sr0            11:0    1    4M  0 rom 
  # cryptsetup status /dev/mapper/encswap
  /dev/mapper/encswap is active and is in use.
  type:    PLAIN
  cipher:  aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
  keysize: 256 bits
  key location: dm-crypt
  device:  /dev/mapper/vg0-swap
  sector size:  512
  offset:  0 sectors
  size:    4194304 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

So, to make this persistent, `/etc/crypttab` contains:

```
swap  /dev/mapper/encswap  /dev/urandom  plain,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,hash=sha256,swap,noearly
```

And `/etc/fstab` contains:

```
/dev/mapper/swap none swap sw 0 0
```

When the system boots up, `dm-crypt` or `systemd` runs through the default 90s timeout, so appears to be waiting for a key which never arrives. The syslog says much the same thing - timed out waiting `/dev/mapper/encswap`. When boot completes, `swapon -s` shows nothing, and `lsblk` doesn't show an `encswap` device (or any swap device). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/etc/crypttab` looks wrong:

```
swap  /dev/mapper/encswap  /dev/urandom  plain,cipher...
```

The second field should be the device that contains the encrypted data, which would be `/dev/mapper/vg0-swap`. I don't think `noearly` is valid, so try

```
swap  /dev/mapper/vg0-swap  /dev/urandom  swap,plain,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,hash=sha256
```

You can debug by running `/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-cryptsetup-generator`. This reads `/etc/crypttab` and creates a unit file in `/tmp`; find the file, and run the start command in there directly. This will give you much more useful logging/debug output.